# How to compute a new variable in a data frame based on a loop in an existing column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame with a loop in a column (starting from 1 to a random number and then starting from 1 again), like this:

```
columnA <- c(1:4,1:5,1:4,1:6,1:5,1:4)
```

Now I would like a second column where every time the number 1 comes in column A it's number goes up by one. So in this instance it would look like this:

```
 columnB <- c(rep(1,4),rep(2,5),rep(3,4),rep(4,6),rep(5,5),rep(6,4))
 df <- data.frame(columnA, columnB)
```

Is there a way to get columnB without manually counting the repetitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is a cumulative sum of `A==1` For example

```
columnB <- cumsum(columnA==1)
```

This way you basically "add 1 " each time you see a 1.

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve it :-)

```
library(data.table)

cumsum((columnA-shift(columnA,fill=0))!=1)+1
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6
```